# XSLT How to skip some elements during create from attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

output date:

```
<products>
<group>
<product symbol="LEC-PY1010C" ean="5901436709251" price_pln="29.05" price_eur="6.56" tax="23.0000" stock="1215">
<name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
<images><gfx>https://linktoimage.com/</gfx><gfx>https://linktoimage2.com/</gfx></images>
<category><id>3091</id><name>Akcesoria antenowe</name></category>
</product>
</group>
</products>
```

XSLT `1.0`

CODE:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="group/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>  
    


<xsl:template match="@symbol">
    <symbol>
        <xsl:text>CPF-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </symbol>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

```
 <products>
    <product>
    <symbol>CPF-LEC-PY1010C</symbol>
    <ean>5901436709251</ean>
    <price_pln>29.05</price_pln>
    <price_eur>6.56</price_eur>
    <tax>23.0000</tax>
    <stock>1215</stock>
    <name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
   <images><gfx>https://linktoimage.com</gfx><gfx>https://linktoimage2.com</gfx></images>
    <category><id>2029</id><name>100 mm</name></category>
    </product>
     </products>
```

Does anyone have any idea:

1. How to delete tag `<id>` and get only text from tag `<name>`  which is between element `<category>` to get result: `<category>100 mm</category>`
2. How to delete tag `<images>` and get only element `<gfx>` and number this element example `<gfx1>https://linktoimage.com</gfx1><gfx2>https://linktoimage2.com</gfx2>`

example result from above:

```
<symbol>CPF-LEC-PY1010C</symbol>
<ean>5901436709251</ean>
<price_pln>29.05</price_pln>
<price_eur>6.56</price_eur>
<tax>23.0000</tax>
<stock>1215</stock>
<name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
<description>test</description>
<category>100 mm</category>
<gfx1>https://linktoimage.com</gfx1>
<gfx2>https://linktoimage2.com</gfx2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following two templates (possibly in combination with the *identity template*):

1. "only text from tag `<name>` which is between element `<category>`"

   ```
    <xsl:template match="category">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>   <!-- Or possibly ".//name" -->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   ```
2. "get only element `<gfx>` and number this element"

   ```
    <xsl:template match="images">
        <xsl:for-each select="gfx">
            <xsl:element name="{concat('gfx',position())}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
   ```

For this to work, remove the `<xsl:template match="product">...` template and replace it with the *identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```